# eclipselink history policy: history records with null id

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I'm trying to use Eclipselink History Policy according to the following example:
https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/History

However, in my case the updates/deletes are not being saved as expected, id field is saved as null as follows:

1)insertion

```
EMP_ID  FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME  SALARY ADDRESS_ID  START_DATE        END_DATE
  1       Bob        Way      55000   6          2010-06-10-12:00   null
```

2) update

```
EMP_ID  FIRSTNAME LASTNAME SALARY   ADDRESS_ID  START_DATE       END_DATE
 1      Bob       Way      55000    6          2010-06-10-12:00   2010-06-10-12:03
 null   Bob       Way      50000    6          2010-06-10-12:03   null
```

3) deletion : nothing happens

I've used mysql and postgresql to perform this tests. My history table is not using any constraints or identity fields.
Is this the right behavior of history feature? Is there something else to configure?

Comment: You've made a change in there as well - show the object you are calling remove/delete on.  Could you have tried nulling out the ID?

Comment: When running on debug mode, entity id is not null after commit operation, however sql is not using it on update.  
 Here's the generated sql :
UPDATE employee SET SALARY = ? WHERE (EMP_ID = ?)
bind => [50000, 1] 

UPDATE employee_hist SET END_DATE = ? WHERE ((END_DATE IS NULL) AND (EMP_ID = ?))
bind => [2016-03-01 16:08:05.405, 1] 

INSERT INTO employee_hist (ADDRESS_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, SALARY, START_DATE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
bind => [null, Bob, Way, 50000, 2016-03-01 16:08:05.405]